# Homework questions with Compensated Attenuator

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

This is for my electronics course and this is for our homework. It covers an RC filter network which I found is called a compensated attenuator. My class which we should've covered a lot on filters, we didn't. So I'm a little lost on the problem

The circuit we reference is theveinized to show how the LPF and HPF can be extracted from the network and how their outputs can be summed to find the output of the network shown at the beginning. That part I understand, but when we go to the problems(we are doing 1,2 and 3) I am totally lost on all of them.

[image: Circuit Diagram & Questions]
[image]

Comment: Homework needs an attempt at a solution or it will be closed

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to answer these home work questions but I can show you how to determine the transfer function of this network in a swift and effortless manner. For this purpose, I will use the [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). The principle lies in determining the time constants of a given circuit in two different conditions: zeroed excitation (the input source is reduced to 0 V and replaced by a short circuit in your case) and nulled output (the excitation is back in place but does reach the output, leading to a 0 in the response). First, we will determine the gain (or attenuation in this resistive case) when \$s=0\$. To do that, open the caps as shown below:

[image]

The gain is simply \$H_0=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$

Then, to obtain the time constant as indicated in your text, we reduce the excitation source \$V_{in}\$ to 0 V and replace it by a short. Then, we "look" through the individual capacitors terminal and determine the resistance:

[image]

But here, you see that both capacitors are in parallel. Despite the presence of two energy-storing elements, this is a 1st-order circuit with a single time constant. This is what is called a degenerate case in which the state variables of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ are not independent but included in a loop with \$V_{in}\$: you loose one order in the denominator degree. The time constant in this case is \$\tau_2=(C_1+C_2)(R_1||R_2)\$. The pole in a 1st-order circuit is the inverse of the time constant: \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau_2}=\frac{1}{(C_1+C_2)(R_1||R_2)}\$.

The zero is obtained by looking at an impedance condition in this circuit in which the excitation \$V_{in}\$ would not produce a response \$V_{out}\$.

[image]

This is when the impedance made of \$C_1\$ paralleled with \$R_1\$ becomes infinite. Otherwise stated, \$Z_1(s)=\frac{N(s)}{1+sR_1C_1}=0\$ when \$s_z=-\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$ or \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$. This is it, the complete transfer function is expressed as \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{1}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{1}{\omega_p}}\$. The below Mathcad sheet shows the expression at work and compares the results with the brute-force expression in the upper right corner:

[image]

I have purposely selected two different time constants but the principle is to match them to obtain flat magnitude and phase responses. You can see thanks to the *low-entropy* factorization that \$H_0\$ sets the dc attenuation (but if the 1-Mohm scope input impedance comes in || with \$R_2\$, it slightly changes the picture) but also the output resistance. The FACTs are unbeatable in terms of efficiency and ease of implementation. You saw how I could obtain this transfer function via three simple sketches that I could later individually fix in case of a typo.